# Create more than one procedure in a SQL file?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I want to create more than one procedure in a SQL file, ie:

```
create or replace procedure pro1 as 
begin
   null;
end pro1;

create or replace procedure pro2 as 
begin
   null;
end pro2;

create or replace procedure pro3 as 
begin
   null;
end pro3;
```

Doing this throws an error:

> Error(10,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CREATE"

How can I do this? Creating a package ins't an option due to some limitations.

Comment: Add a trailing slash after each procedure. See this question and answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7233210/is-there-a-way-to-create-multiple-triggers-in-one-script/7233286#7233286

Comment: For the record this is bad practice.  It is a much better idea to have one procedure per file, because then we can use *source control* to manage our PL/SQL.  Oh, and the file name should reflect the procedure name (obviously).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Add /

```
create or replace procedure pro1 as 
begin
   null;
end pro1;
/

create or replace procedure pro2 as 
begin
   null;
end pro2;
/

create or replace procedure pro3 as 
begin
   null;
end pro3;
/
```

Comment: Adding trailing slash gave me this error **Error(10,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "/" **

Comment: running it via sqlplus? it can get upset about the spaces between code depending on your settings

Comment: My bad, I was changing the procedure itself directly from the SQLDeveloper rather than changing the SQL file :) ..

Comment: Thanks a lot , you saved my time

Comment: I have SQL Error [42601]: ERREUR: synthax error near « / » on postgres v11