# Keep getting an error and do not understand why

Tags: plsql, sequence, procedure

sales_heads will compile with no errors but when I try to compile sales_lines it comes up with 2 errors which are:

1. Error(3,1): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
2. Error(3,111): PL/SQL: ORA-02289: sequence does not exist

could someone tell me where I am going wrong.

---

```
drop sequence nsale_seq;

CREATE SEQUENCE nsale_seq
 START WITH     1000000000
 INCREMENT BY   1
 NOCACHE
 NOCYCLE;

create or replace PROCEDURE sale_heads (staffID_new number, customerID_new number)
is begin
insert into SALE_HEAD (sale_num, sale_date, status, staff_id, customer_id) values (nsale_seq.NEXTVAL, sysdate, 'P', staffID_new, customerID_new);
end sale_heads;
/


create or replace PROCEDURE sales_lines (productCode_new number, quantity_new number, actualPrice_new number) is
begin
insert into SALE_LINE (actual_price, quantity, sale_num, product_code) values (actualPrice_new, quantity_new, nsale_seg.CURRVAL, productCode_new);
end sales_lines;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

You have placed `/` this after your first procedure as well as after second procedure. `/` is used to show the end of the file or the statements to be executed!Hence, it's unable to find second procedure!!!

That's why your second procedure is getting ignored.

Please remove the `/` first slash after first procedure `sale_heads`.

I believe it'll work perfectly!

Comment: it took both errors away, however a new error occurs now it is coming up with an error 'Error(8,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CREATE" '

Comment: @HarryMinhas-Are you sure there is no other code in this file???
If so,please try removing the second `/` also! Also,as there are 2 procedures,so your original statement was much better. I'll make an answer edit for you after you answer this query!

Comment: @HarryMinhas-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7984619/more-than-one-procedure-in-1-file