# Run multiple Create Triggers at once in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, scripting, triggers

I'm hoping this is again, a case of very silly semi-colon misplacement. Is there a way to get multiple triggers to run at once? In this current state, it will run the last CREATE TRIGGER but that's it.

```
delimiter |

CREATE TRIGGER menu_button_soa_update_time AFTER UPDATE on `menu_button`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE soa_config 
    SET parameterValue = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    WHERE parameterName = 'last_menu_update_time';

END
|
delimiter ;

\

delimiter |

CREATE TRIGGER mbi_soa_update_time AFTER UPDATE on `menu_button_info`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE soa_config 
    SET parameterValue = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    WHERE parameterName = 'last_menu_update_time';

END
|
delimiter ;

\

delimiter |

CREATE TRIGGER mbs_soa_update_time AFTER UPDATE on `menu_button_size`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE soa_config 
    SET parameterValue = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    WHERE parameterName = 'last_menu_update_time';

END
|
delimiter ;
```

I've tried looking at:
 [Is there a way to create multiple triggers in one script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7233210/is-there-a-way-to-create-multiple-triggers-in-one-script) (FYI: I know the link shows / but I get the following error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '/

CREATE TRIGGER mbi_soa_update_time AFTER UPDATE on `menu_button_info`
FOR EAC' at line 1
```

and other googlenomics. Getting rid of the delimiters didn't seem to help (I couldn't run a single create trigger).

Answer (score 1):

In mysql you can just rely on the delimiter.
I just tried it in my database and it works.
However, just remember that you can't define more than one of the same type of trigger on the same table. Try something like this to test:

```
delimiter |

CREATE TRIGGER menu_button_soa_update_time AFTER UPDATE on `menu_button`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE soa_config 
    SET parameterValue = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    WHERE parameterName = 'last_menu_update_time';

END |

CREATE TRIGGER mbi_soa_update_time AFTER UPDATE on `menu_button_info`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE soa_config 
    SET parameterValue = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    WHERE parameterName = 'last_menu_update_time';

END |

delimiter ;
```