# Oracle APEX don't create triggers when import sql file

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex, navicat

I have a SQL file exported from `Oracle Express` (most probably with Navicat Lite), and there are queries of creating triggers.

But after I imported the file with APEX (`SQL Workshop` -> `SQL Script`), the triggers are not created successfully, with no errors.

The queries are like this, they are definitely valid, and I can successfully create the triggers when I manually run these queries with `SQL Command`.

create or replace TRIGGER "RESENV"."AREA_ID_AUTOINCREMENT" BEFORE INSERT ON "RESENV"."AREA" REFERENCING OLD AS "OLD" NEW AS "NEW" FOR EACH ROW WHEN (new.id is null) 
    begin 
    select area_id_seq.nextval into :new.id from dual; 
    end;;

```
-- ---------------------------- 
-- Checks structure for table "RESENV"."AREA" 
-- ---------------------------- 
ALTER TABLE "RESENV"."AREA" ADD CHECK ("ID" IS NOT NULL); 
ALTER TABLE "RESENV"."AREA" ADD CHECK ("NAME" IS NOT NULL); 

-- ---------------------------- 
-- Checks structure for table "RESENV"."DATASET" 
-- ---------------------------- 
ALTER TABLE "RESENV"."DATASET" ADD CHECK ("SYSTEM_ID" IS NOT NULL); 
ALTER TABLE "RESENV"."DATASET" ADD CHECK ("AREA_ID" IS NOT NULL); 
ALTER TABLE "RESENV"."DATASET" ADD CHECK ("TABLE_NAME" IS NOT NULL); 
ALTER TABLE "RESENV"."DATASET" ADD CHECK ("CREATED" IS NOT NULL); 

-- ---------------------------- 
-- Triggers structure for table "RESENV"."IDX" 
-- ---------------------------- 
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "RESENV"."IDX_ID_AUTOINCREMENT" BEFORE INSERT ON "RESENV"."IDX" REFERENCING OLD AS "OLD" NEW AS "NEW" FOR EACH ROW ENABLE WHEN (new.id is null) 
begin  
    select idx_id_seq.nextval into :new.id from dual; 
end;; 

-- ---------------------------- 
-- Checks structure for table "RESENV"."IDX" 
-- ---------------------------- 
ALTER TABLE "RESENV"."IDX" ADD CHECK ("ID" IS NOT NULL); 

-- ---------------------------- 
-- Triggers structure for table "RESENV"."SYSTEM" 
-- ---------------------------- 
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "RESENV"."SYSTEM_ID_AUTOINCREMENT" BEFORE INSERT ON "RESENV"."SYSTEM" REFERENCING OLD AS "OLD" NEW AS "NEW" FOR EACH ROW ENABLE WHEN (new.id is null) 
begin  
    select SYSTEM_ID_SEQ.nextval into :new.id from dual; 
end;; 

-- ---------------------------- 
-- Checks structure for table "RESENV"."SYSTEM" 
-- ---------------------------- 
ALTER TABLE "RESENV"."SYSTEM" ADD CHECK ("ID" IS NOT NULL); 
ALTER TABLE "RESENV"."SYSTEM" ADD CHECK ("SYSTEM_CREATED" IS NOT NULL); 
ALTER TABLE "RESENV"."SYSTEM" ADD CHECK ("SYSTEM_MODIFIED" IS NOT NULL); 
ALTER TABLE "RESENV"."SYSTEM" ADD CHECK ("USER_ID" IS NOT NULL); 

-- ---------------------------- 
-- Checks structure for table "RESENV"."UNIT" 
-- ---------------------------- 
ALTER TABLE "RESENV"."UNIT" ADD CHECK ("ID" IS NOT NULL); 
ALTER TABLE "RESENV"."UNIT" ADD CHECK ("NAME" IS NOT NULL); 
ALTER TABLE "RESENV"."UNIT" ADD CHECK ("GD_ID" IS NOT NULL); 
ALTER TABLE "RESENV"."UNIT" ADD CHECK ("AREA_ID" IS NOT NULL); 

-- ---------------------------- 
-- Checks structure for table "RESENV"."USERS" 
-- ---------------------------- 
ALTER TABLE "RESENV"."USERS" ADD CHECK ("ID" IS NOT NULL); 
ALTER TABLE "RESENV"."USERS" ADD CHECK ("NAME" IS NOT NULL); 
ALTER TABLE "RESENV"."USERS" ADD CHECK ("PASSWORD" IS NOT NULL); 

-- ---------------------------- 
-- Checks structure for table "RESENV"."VLUE" 
-- ---------------------------- 
ALTER TABLE "RESENV"."VLUE" ADD CHECK ("ID" IS NOT NULL); 
ALTER TABLE "RESENV"."VLUE" ADD CHECK ("UNIT_ID" IS NOT NULL); 
ALTER TABLE "RESENV"."VLUE" ADD CHECK ("IDX_ID" IS NOT NULL); 
ALTER TABLE "RESENV"."VLUE" ADD CHECK ("IDX_VALUE" IS NOT NULL); 
​
```

I have tried many times, and same result.

Why this happen? Is this a bug of APEX?

### UPDATE

I have these lines shown above at the end of the SQL file (before those are the lines of creating tables and inserting data), but APEX treated all these lines as ONE statement, and created only one trigger whose code is as above (of course there is an error in the code of the trigger, but APEX didn't mention that when run the SQL script).

I have tried with Navicat to import the dump file (with `Execute SQL file` function). And the errors are as listed, which I think it should be OK.

### Update 2

It turns out I have to add a slash `/` at the end of each `create trigger` statement, otherwise there can only be one trigger created in each script file.
[see this questin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7233210/is-there-a-way-to-create-multiple-triggers-in-one-script)

But the triggers still have errors with the above statements and a slash.

The code is:

```
create or replace TRIGGER "RESENV"."SYSTEM_ID_AUTOINCREMENT" BEFORE INSERT ON "RESENV"."SYSTEM" REFERENCING OLD AS "OLD" NEW AS "NEW" FOR EACH ROW WHEN (new.id is null) 
begin  
    select SYSTEM_ID_SEQ.nextval into :new.id from dual; 
end;;
```

​
and the error is: `Line 3 Position 5, PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";"`

I don't know why navcat exported like this.

### Update

It turns out that the double semicolons caused the problem. After I removed one, there is no error any more.

Comment: Go to `SQL Script`, find your script, then click on a number in the column `Results`. A new report about running this script will be opened, click there in the column `View results`. There you will see error messages.

Comment: @Dmitry The question is, there is no error at all.

Comment: Statements Processed 1133
Successful 1133
With Errors 0

Comment: Did you search this trigger in system views? Try to run query `drop trigger "RESENV"."IDX_ID_AUTOINCREMENT"`. What is the response of DBMS?

Comment: @Dmitry It said: trigger 'IDX_ID_AUTOINCREMENT' does not exist. I checked the result of  `SQL Script`, and there is only one trigger-creating statement, while I have 3 similar triggers just like this one. I think Oracle failed to create the triggers but didn't throw an error. As a result, there is only one trigger in the database, and the code of the trigger shown in `Object details` is all the following code from the line of creating the trigger.

Comment: It is very strange. I tried to reproduce in my system - all works fine. Triggers was successfully created. In a case of errors log contained error messages. Oracle 12.1, APEX 4.2.6. Looks like a bug.

Comment: Do the table "RESENV"."IDX"  exists prior to the script execution?

Comment: @Dmitry Thank you! Then I should try the new version and also Navicat Lite.

Comment: @Typo Yes, all the lines before this part is about creating tables and sequences, and inserting data.

Comment: @Dmitry I have tried with Navicat's `Execute SQL file` function, and there are errors, so it might not the APEX's problem. But I don't see why there're error 'cause I get the dump file from Navicat.